# How to check if random points lies inside 2D region

Tags: matlab, plot, contour

I have the following code:

```
clc; clear all;
M = 6;
x=-3:0.1:3;
y=x; [X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y); contour(x,y,X.^2/2+sqrt(2)./2*Y.^2+2*sin(X.*Y),1)

random_numbers = -3+6*rand(2*M,1);
```

What i would like to do is to perform a monte Carlo integration where contour(...) shows the region where I would like to compute it. I would like to have a code which looks similar to this:

```
for i = 1:M
    if random_numbers(i) is in contourplot
        do f(i+1) = f + f(x(i));
    end
end
```

That is; loop through every random_number, check if the a random point lies somewhere in the region, if it does evaluate the function in that given point and sum it with it's previous value. If it doesn't, continue the loop. I know I can't use "do" and "is in", but I just wanted to show you some pseudocode of how I would like the code to execute things.

My question is if I somehow can check if a given point lies somewhere in the region. I have seen MATLAB's "inpolygon" and it does almost exactly what I want. But it seems like it doesn't work for functions, e.g. it works only for polygons.

Down below you can see the contour.

[image]

Comment: Then make a polygon out of your functions? You plot the thing somehow, which means you got a list of `x,y` coordinates, which serves as input for `inpolygon`

Comment: How about this: fill the contour and check the color of the random coordinates.

Comment: In addition to the duplicate, this post by the legendary Paul Bourke may be of interest: http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonmesh#insidepoly